# ClassNotFoundException while trying to create Air Native Extension of YouTube API

Tags: android, apache-flex, actionscript, air, youtube-api

I created a clean air native extension with a simple function that starts an activity from within the ANE, 'DumbActivity'. It worked.

However, after having DumbActivity extend YouTubeFailureRecoveryActivity in order to start using the YouTube API 3.0, I got a ClassNotFoundException on DumbActivity when I run the ANE. Worht mentioning that when I run the code as a native android app, it runs properly, and I can use YouTube abilities.
Also checked, the DumbActivity class is included in the Jar.

Is that some sort of library conflict or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to copy the external Jar used to /android, then created platform-options-android.xml 
and add -platformoptions platform-options-android.xml to the command line of the ANE creation.